# How to network multiple iOS devices programatically without WiFI and Server, just use Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth

I have a strange user requirement. The user requires the app can network each other app users, and broadcast small data package to other devices. However, we can't use back-end server, and user devices might not in the same WiFi networks. The only technology I can imaging is Bluetooth.

Is it possible to network multiple devices with iOS devices' Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have a look at [Multipeer Connectivity framework](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/)